# how to execute batch file from C/C++ w/o console window?

Tags: c++, c, windows, batch-file, console

I'm executing batch file from a C++ program by `system("start /B mybatch.bat")` call, where `/B` is supposed to run batch file w/o console window. But it's still visible.

Edit: I resolved the issue by `ShellExecute()` as was proposed in comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use CreateProcess instead ?

Comment: Or [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153\(v=vs.85\).aspx) which might be simpler.

Comment: @user: `ShellExecute` doesn't allow you to pass in a `STARTUPINFO` structure, which allows the window to be hidden.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It does however have `nShowCmd`. I don't know if it that will work for the OP, but I figured the alternative function was worth mentioning.

Comment: I used `system()` call just because it's so simple. I don't see this call console window, I see my batch file console window that I execute by `start /B mybatch.bat`. This flag is supposed to run the command w/o creating a new window: `Start application without creating a new window. The application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt the application.` Does I misunderstand this statement, is batch executed in the same window instead of launching separate process as `start` command usually does?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you don't use Windows Runtime, you can try `_popen` or `_wpopen`: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I used it mainly because `_popen` creates a pipe so I can easily read output as well.